# In SailsJS, how do I check in a view partial that a route is active

Tags: sails.js

I have a set of links in a partial that i'd want to change visually depending if the route they go to is active.

Is there a way to check if a route is active from the view?

Comment: What do you mean by "active"?

Comment: when the user is currently on that route. like if i have a profile page route /profile/:id and i want an anchor tag that links to the profile page to have an active class

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, it sounds like you're just looking to see which URL was requested?

The `req` object, which holds information about the current request, is available as a local variable in all views.  So inside your view you can check `req.url` to determine which URL the user requested.  If the view was rendered via a controller using `res.view` (rather than being rendered directly as a result of a [view route](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/routes/custom-routes#?view-target-syntax)), you can also check which controller/action was run by looking at `req.options.controller` and `req.options.action`.  See the [docs on req.options](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/request-req/req-options) for more info.